# if statement in an array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a array I have to post (json). But the value `accountNr` should either be `$val_nc_iban` or should be NULL depending on a certain value outside this array. So how can I either echo `$val_nc_iban` (is a string) or NULL (not string) inside an array depending on the outside value?

```
   $curl_post_data_nc = array(
    "person" => array(
        "title" => "$val_nc_persontitle",
        "nationalNr" => NULL,
        "firstName" => "$val_nc_personfirstname",
        "lastName" => "$val_nc_personsurname",
        "birthDate" => "$new_val_nc_persondob"
    ),

    "company" => array(
        "type" => "$val_nc_companytype",
        "name" => "$val_nc_companyname",
        "vat" => "$val_nc_companyvat",
        "nace" => "$val_nc_companynace",
        "website" => NULL
    ),

    "contact" => array(
            "email" => "$val_nc_personemail",
            "mobile" => "$val_nc_personphone",
            "telephone" => NULL
    ),

    "contract" => array(
        "referenceDate" => "$val_nc_refdate",
        "startDate" => "$val_nc_startdate"
    ),

    "payment" => array(
        "paymentMethodEmail" => false,
        "paymentMethodMail" => true,
        "paymentInterval" => "$val_nc_paymentbilling",
        "method" => "$val_nc_paymentmethod",
        "accountNr" => $val_nc_result = ($val_nc_paymentmethod == 'TRANSFER') ? NULL : "$val_nc_iban"
    ),

    "deliveryAddress" => array(
        "building" => "HOUSE",
        "street" => "$val_nc_personstreet",
        "streetNr" => "$val_nc_personstreetnr",
        "floor" => NULL,
        "boxNr" => NULL,
        "localityCode" => "$val_nc_personpostcode",
        "localityName" => "$val_nc_personlocality"
    ),

    "invoiceAddress" => array(
        "sameAsDelivery" => false,
        "building" => "HOUSE",
        "street" => "$val_nc_billstreet",
        "streetNr" => "$val_nc_billstreetnr",
        "floor" => NULL,
        "boxNr" => NULL,
        "localityCode" => "$val_nc_billpostcode",
        "localityName" => "$val_nc_billlocality"   
    ),

    "gasMeter" => array(
        "ean" => "$val_nc_ean",
        "nr" => NULL,
        "type" => "gas",
        "electric" => NULL,
        "gas" => array(
                   "usage"   => $val_nc_gasusage,
                   "formula" => "TTF103532"
                )  
    ),
```

Comment: ... What have you tried ?

Comment: What do you mean by "outside" value. The only way to know is to look at the actual value and see if it's `NULL` or not.

Comment: I tried to do an if-statement outside the array and and echo the right value but the quotes are the problem. If I echo the right value with quotes around it (append) it does not work.

Comment: @Gerard You can escape the quotes or echo using a HEREDOC.

Comment: Depending on a value I have to post a string or post NULL

Comment: Are you familiar with the ternary operator? It will probably help you here.

Comment: Thank you @jonhopkins! Ternary operator it is!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put the variables in quotes? You can use their actual value in the array!

Example:

```
$curl_post_data_nc = array(
"person" => array(
    "title" => $val_nc_persontitle,
    "nationalNr" => NULL,
    "firstName" => $val_nc_personfirstname,
    "lastName" => $val_nc_personsurname,
    "birthDate" => $new_val_nc_persondob
),

"company" => array(
    "type" => $val_nc_companytype,
    "name" => $val_nc_companyname,
    "vat" => $val_nc_companyvat,
    "nace" => $val_nc_companynace,
    "website" => NULL
),

"contact" => array(
        "email" => $val_nc_personemail,
        "mobile" => $val_nc_personphone,
        "telephone" => NULL
),

"contract" => array(
    "referenceDate" => $val_nc_refdate,
    "startDate" => $val_nc_startdate
),

"payment" => array(
    "paymentMethodEmail" => false,
    "paymentMethodMail" => true,
    "paymentInterval" => $val_nc_paymentbilling,
    "method" => $val_nc_paymentmethod,
    "accountNr" => $val_nc_result = ($val_nc_paymentmethod == 'TRANSFER') ? NULL : $val_nc_iban
),

"deliveryAddress" => array(
    "building" => "HOUSE",
    "street" => $val_nc_personstreet,
    "streetNr" => $val_nc_personstreetnr,
    "floor" => NULL,
    "boxNr" => NULL,
    "localityCode" => $val_nc_personpostcode,
    "localityName" => $val_nc_personlocality
),

"invoiceAddress" => array(
    "sameAsDelivery" => false,
    "building" => "HOUSE",
    "street" => $val_nc_billstreet,
    "streetNr" => $val_nc_billstreetnr,
    "floor" => NULL,
    "boxNr" => NULL,
    "localityCode" => $val_nc_billpostcode,
    "localityName" => $val_nc_billlocality   
),

"gasMeter" => array(
    "ean" => $val_nc_ean,
    "nr" => NULL,
    "type" => "gas",
    "electric" => NULL,
    "gas" => array(
               "usage"   => $val_nc_gasusage,
               "formula" => "TTF103532"
            )  
),
```